# tkinter get int value instead of nonetype

Tags: python, tkinter

Does anyone know why `var2.set(E2.get())` function gets none type not int?

```
var1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
E1 = Tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = var1  ,bd =5)
E1.pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
n =  var1.set(E1.get())
```

and I got this error:

> File "/home/rostom/Desktop/statistic.py", line 36, in estimate_prob
>       for m in range(0,m):
>   TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got NoneType.

the whole code

```
import numpy as np
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
root = Tkinter.Tk()
var1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
var2 = Tkinter.IntVar()
var3 = Tkinter.IntVar()
var4 = Tkinter.IntVar()
text1= Tkinter.StringVar()
text2= Tkinter.StringVar()
text3= Tkinter.StringVar()
text4= Tkinter.StringVar()

def seq_sum(n):
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 0

    for i in range(0,n):

        r = np.random.rand()
        if r > 0.5:
            x1=x1+1
        else:
            x2=x2+1
    return x1

def estimate_prob(n,k1,k2,m):
    ran=0
    for m in range(0,m):
        head = seq_sum(n)


        if k1<=head < k2:

           ran =ran  + 1

    p = ran/float(m)
    print ran

    return tkMessageBox.showinfo("results ", p)


L1 = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = text1)
L1.grid(row=0,column=0)
E1 = Tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = var1  ,bd =5)
E1.grid(row=0,column=1)

text1.set("number of flips ")

n =  var1.set(E1.get())

L2 = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = text2)
L2.grid(row=1,column=0)
E2 = Tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = var2  ,bd =5)
E2.grid(row=1,column=1)

text2.set("lower limit ")

k1 = var2.set(E2.get())

L3 = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = text3)
L3.grid(row=2,column=0)
E3 = Tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = var3  ,bd =5)
E3.grid(row=2,column=2)

text3.set("upper limit ")

k2= var3.set(E3.get())

L4 = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = text4)
L4.grid(row=3,column=0)
E4 = Tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable = var4  ,bd =5)
E4.grid(row=3,column=1)

text4.set("number of trials ")

m = var4.set(E4.get())

B1 = Tkinter.Button(root,text = "calculate the probability", command = lambda:  estimate_prob(n,k1,k2,m) )
B1.grid(row=4,column=1)  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please format your code. What is `var1` here? Please provide a reproducible example. Providing library version also helps.

Comment: Your error was not produced by this code. It was probably caused by an attempt to use `n` in the next, missing, line of code. Please include _all_ relevant code and the _complete_ error message.

Comment: I meant `var2`. Where is `var2` in the code snippet? `var1` is already defined.

Comment: @narendra-choudhary Either way, `var.set()` returns a `None` which the OP presumably attempts to use later in their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement looks really weird:

```
m = var4.set(E4.get())
```

Why not write it as

```
m = var4.get()
```

since `var4` is the IntVar assigned to `E4`? When you **set** an IntVar, the operation returns `None`.

```
var4.set(E4.get()) == None
```

This goes for all four IntVars.